# Deactivate code made with add_filter

Tags: filters

In WordPress I have a calendar (With the "Events Calendar Plugin"). I want this calendar to be for logged in users only. So I used this code:

```
add_filter( 'tribe_events_pre_get_posts', 'redirect_from_events' );
function redirect_from_events( $query ) {
         // print_r("hey");

  if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    return;
 
  if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->get( 'eventDisplay' ) ){
      //print_r("hey");
    return;
  }
  // Look for a page with a slug of "logged-in-users-only".
  $target_page = get_posts( [
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'name' => 'logged-in-users-only'
   ] );
 
  // Use the target page URL if found, else use the home page URL.
  if ( empty( $target_page ) ) {
    $url = get_home_url();
      print_r($url);
  } else {
    $target_page = current( $target_page );
    $url = get_permalink( $target_page->ID );
          print_r($url);

  }
   
  // Redirect!
  wp_safe_redirect( $url );
  exit;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'restrict_events', 100 );
function restrict_events( $where_sql ) {
  global $wpdb;
  if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Main' ) ) {
    return $where_sql;
  }
  return $wpdb->prepare( " $where_sql AND $wpdb->posts.post_type <> %s ", Tribe__Events__Main::POSTTYPE );
}
```

Now I want to cancel this code. I trued commenting it but it's still working. I am not sure but I think I should use Remove_filter to accomplish this. So I created another snippet:

```
remove_filter( 'tribe_events_pre_get_posts', 'redirect_from_events' );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'restrict_events', 100 );
```

Comment: That ought to work, yes, as long as it runs after the original code. When you say cancel it though do you mean always? Then it would be simpler to just comment out the add_filter()s in the original code. Or conditionally? Then it would be easier to add the conditions to the existing code the same as you have with is_user_logged_in(). Where is this code, in a separate plugin? You could also just disable the plugin, if there's nothing else in there you want.

Comment: I installed "Snippets" plugin and just created a new snippet and put the codes in two different snippets.

Comment: Do you have caching plugins installed.  If you comment out the code it should stop executing unless for some reason it's cached and still persists.